# Remix error: "Expected token LBrace got 'View' function get() public view returns (uint)"

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, dapps

I have this error during the compiling of the code below on Remix.

Someone could help me ?

```
    pragma solidity 0.4.4;
    contract SimpleStorage{
    uint storeddata;
    function set(uint x) public{
        storeddata = x;
    }
    function get() public view returns(uint){
        return storeddata;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a valid compiler version. (You perhaps missed out a `2`, but you'll need to decide which version you actually want to use. Probably a post-`0.5.0` version.)

This compiles:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storeddata;

    function set(uint x) public {
        storeddata = x;
    }

    function get() public view returns(uint) {
        return storeddata; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Was just about to answer about the same, but all brackets are correct in original post as well, aren't they?

Comment: You're right - when I loaded Remix I must have over-written what was already there but missed the last line :-) (Should have `ctrl-a`-ed!) Thanks for spotting it :-)

Comment: Yes, the problem was the version, thank you so much!